# Retrieving Facebook Lead Data

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, sdk

I tryed to use this code to retrieving Facebook Lead Data

```
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
me = AdUser(fbid='me')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts(fields=['name']))
my_account = my_accounts[3]
ads = my_account.get_ads(params=params)

for ad in ads[10:20]:
    print(ad.get_leads())
```

But I get an empty response {"data": []} for each ad.
In ADS Manager, I see that there are leads.

App permissions:
pages_show_list,
ads_management,
leads_retrieval,
pages_read_engagement,
pages_read_user_content,
pages_manage_ads.

Second try:

```
params = {
    'access_token':access_token
}

adgroup_id = ad_id

if access_token:
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/%s/leads' %adgroup_id
    resp = session.get(url=url, params=params)
    
print(resp.text)
```

Annswer: {"data":[]}

Please tell me what needs to be added to get the correct result?

Comment: Have you made sure all the requirements mentioned under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving are fulfilled?

Comment: I used this manual.